# Use subquery results in main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

How can I make subquery result available in the main query like this example?

```
SELECT Id AS ParticipantId, TeamId,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date), 0) AS FirstWeight,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date DESC), 0) AS LastWeight,
FirstWeight - LastWeight As WeightDiff // this doesn't work
FROM Participants
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirstWeight,LastWeight in line Alias will not work sql server you can change your query below way

```
SELECT Id AS ParticipantId, TeamId,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date), 0) AS FirstWeight,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date DESC), 0) AS LastWeight,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date), 0)- ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date DESC), 0) As WeightDiff // this doesn't work
FROM Participants
```

or you can use subquery to next level

```
select ParticipantId, TeamId,FirstWeight,LastWeight,
 FirstWeight-LastWeight as WeightDiff from
  ( 
  SELECT Id AS ParticipantId, TeamId,
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date), 0) AS FirstWeight,
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date DESC), 0) AS LastWeight
FROM Participants
  ) as t
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I could make the subqueries again to do the calculation, but I thought there were better approaches. Also with performance in mind.

Comment: @Mads cte or sub-query otherwise have to direct but in alias will not work

Comment: Could you help me complete your second example?

Comment: @Mads i edited that is just your query and make the difference in top query

Comment: Thanks, nice. I give you the correct answer due to performance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to place your current query into a CTE, and then subquery it, making use of the aliases:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id AS ParticipantId, TeamId,
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date), 0) AS FirstWeight,
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) Weight FROM ParticipantData WHERE (ParticipantId = Participants.Id) AND (Weight <> 0) ORDER BY Date DESC), 0) AS LastWeight
    FROM Participants
)

SELECT
    ParticipantId,
    TeamId,
    FirstWeight,
    LastWeight,
    FirstWeight - LastWeight As WeightDiff
FROM cte;
```

Comment: That looks nice. Is it better in performance than multi subqueries?

Comment: No, the multiple subqueries version would probably perform better.  But, it looks much worse, and might be harder to maintain from a coding point of view.  Up to you as to which version you want to use.

Comment: @Mads I spent about 15 minutes trying to rewrite your query using regular joins, but was unable to do so.  You might have to stick with your current approach, assuming you need this exact output.

Comment: You're right it looks much simpler than all the subqueries, but in this case I must have performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT Id AS ParticipantId, TeamId,
       COALESCE(f.FirstWeight, 0) as FirstWeight,
       COALESCE(f.LastWeight, 0) as LastWeight,
       (f.FirstWeight - l.LastWeight) As WeightDiff 
FROM Participants p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP(1) pd.Weight as firstWeight
      FROM ParticipantData pd
      WHERE (pd.ParticipantId = p.Id) AND Weight <> 0
      ORDER BY Date
     ) f OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP(1) pd.Weight as lastWeight
      FROM ParticipantData pd
      WHERE (pd.ParticipantId = p.Id) AND Weight <> 0
      ORDER BY Date DESC
     ) l;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! How is CROSS APPLY in performance versus subqueries / joins?

Comment: @Mads . . . It should be equivalent to subqueries.  You would have to test to see how it compares to `JOIN`s in any particular case.